# Не корректно работает ctrl+w в Google Chrome

Tags: linux, google-chrome

Когда я хочу закрыть вкладку с помощью Ctrl+W всё отрабатывает корректно, но если у меня в этот момент был в фокусе какой-то input на сайте или строка поиска гугл, то у меня просто очищается текст.
Возможно проблема в ОС - использую Manjaro Linux Gnome

Comment: А что тут некорректного? Событие передаётся от текущего фокусированного контрола и далее вверх по иерархии. Первый в этой цепи, кто реагирует на сочетание, его и обрабатывает.

Comment: @Akina  у гугла нет обработчика  ктрл+ц на странице. скорее всего какоето расширение стоит.

Comment: @eri Так этот обработчик может быть, скажем, в коде страницы. Или у стандартного инпута, который использован на странице, или у его фрейма, или ещё где вверх по иерархии.

Comment: ` или строка поиска гугл,` -  у меня отрабатывает нормально